# My button is not appearing in my Window. I am using Tkinter

Tags: tkinter

I am trying to call a class within a class, and my button is not appearing. The quit this window button appears, but not the credit score button. I have a class in the code called CreditScoreChecker. It is at the bottom of the page.

```
class Win2:
    def __init__(self, master, number):
        self.master = master
        self.creditScore = creditscore
        self.master.geometry("350x650")
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.master)
        self.quit = tk.Button(self.frame, text = f"Quit this window ", command = self.close_window)
        self.butnew = ("Credit Score", "1", CreditScoreChecker)
        self.quit.pack()
        self.frame.pack()

    def butnew(self, text, number, _class):
        tk.Button(self.frame, text = text, command= lambda: self.new_window(number, _class)).pack()
    
    def new_window(self, number, _class):
        self.new = tk.Toplevel(self.master)
        _class(self.new, number)









class CreditScoreChecker:
def __init__(self, master, number):
    def creditScore():
        monthlyWage = int(input("What is your monthly wage? "))
        monthlySpendings = int(input("What are your monthly spendings? ")) / 10
        monthlyOverdraft = int(input("What is your monthly overdraft? "))
        monthlySavings = int(input("How much do you add into your savings account per month? ")) / 10
        creditScore = (monthlyWage / monthlyOverdraft) + monthlySpendings - monthlySavings
        print(creditScore)

def new_window(self, number, _class):
    self.new = tk.Toplevel(self.master)
    _class(self.new, number)
```

Comment: Since the code has only class definitions, there is no code on how to initiated the class.  You should provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You never call the method "butnew". Your line code only makes you declare self.butnew as tuple.

```
self.butnew = ("Credit Score", "1", CreditScoreChecker)
```

A method is a block of code which only runs when it is called.:

```
self.butnew("Credit Score", "1", CreditScoreChecker)
```

Comment: This has removed all my buttons on the page, the size of the page is also not being rendered. Any suggestions?

Comment: I edited my answer. Can you try it again with this solution?

Comment: I've used that previously, and it wasn't appearing. Do you want me to show you the class I am trying to call?

Comment: yes please show the rest of the class you want to call

Comment: replacing 'self.butnew = ("Credit Score", "1", CreditScoreChecker)' with 'self.butnew("Credit Score", "1", CreditScoreChecker)' did not work for you?

Comment: Just checked, they are different

Comment: No ''self.butnew = ("Credit Score", "1", CreditScoreChecker)" initialize self.butnew as a tuple with the value ("Credit Score", "1", CreditScoreChecker) and "self.butnew("Credit Score", "1", CreditScoreChecker)" calls the butnew Method which runs "tk.Button(self.frame, text = text, command= lambda: self.new_window(number, _class)).pack()"

Comment: Nope, not working. The Quit This Window button disappears. Can you give an examplen of its implementation